# using xslt to remove info path declarations form info path XML ? <? mso .......>

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, infopath

Using xslt I was able to remove the namespaces, but how do I remove the `<?mso...?>` tags?

I am trying to convert the info path XML to XML and store it in a database.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:Zone-Zero-Observation-Card-with-form-audit-no-approval-mobile-view-Test-1:-myXSD-2012-09-05T20-51-15" solutionVersion="1.0.0.873" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="test.xsn"?>
    <?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
    <?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
```

Below is the xslt I tried but that did not help.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()[starts-with(name(), 'mso-')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want to use the identity transformation pattern to remove some nodes then you need to write a template matching that node that is empty so you need `<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[starts-with(name(), 'mso-')]"/>`. Your posted stylesheet copies the processing instruction, that is no what you want, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of node is called processing-instruction so use

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[starts-with(name(), 'mso-')]"/>
```

together with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

That way the processing instructions where the name starts with `mso-` will not be copied.

I will show a complete stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="text() | comment()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()[starts-with(name(), 'mso-')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```